# Idiomatic way to combine different monads with for in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose we have two values wrapped in different monads (e.g. Try and Option):

```
val x: Option[Int] = Some(10)
val y: Try[Int] = Success(4)
```

and we want to have sum of the values. One would write

```
val z = for {
  xval <- x
  yval <- y
} yield xval + yval
```

but it won't be compiled because of type error. Is there an idiomatic Scala way to deal with this?

Comment: [Monads generally are not composable/combinable](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/monads-do-not-compose/), but with Try you can use .toOption

Comment: You wouldn't really combine monads in Haskell either, you'd just stack them all up creating deeper and deeper nesting

Comment: Monads aren't composable, look for Monad tranformers, something like `TryT[Option, A]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala standard library is missing some useful functions / abstractions, but fortunately there is a complementing library called Scalaz which provides most of what you need.

In particular, as suggested, you are looking for Monad transformers. See these two following posts:

http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html

http://underscoreconsulting.com/blog/posts/2013/12/20/scalaz-monad-transformers.html

Answer (score 2):

Using [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) monad transformer OptionT:

```
val z = (for {
   xval <- OptionT.fromOption(x): OptionT[Try, Int]
   yval <- OptionT.liftF(y)
} yield xval + yval).value
```

However, return type is `Try[Option[Int]]`

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Spiewak's Emm library is able to combine multiple monads, but due to the fact that it does not respect all the monadic laws the libary is only for pedagogical purposes.

Emm Github: https://github.com/djspiewak/emm

Daniel does a presentation on Emm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5Tri3Yow0U

I've also come across FreeK, a library for composing multiple Free monads: https://github.com/ProjectSeptemberInc/freek